# Custom Routes and Declarative Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, declarative-authorization

Don't know if this has been answered before.

Have custom routes to users.  If I access the user directly /users/5 everything works.  If I try /profile or even /users/current_user with Declarative Authorization I get "Couldn't find User without an ID"

```
map.profile "profile", :controller => "users", :action => "show"
map.edit_profile 'profile/edit', :controller => 'users', :action => 'edit', :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

My ApplicationController has

> before_filter { |c|
>   Authorization.current_user =
>   c.current_user }

and my authorization_rules has user.id and also tried current_user.id.

```
role :user do
    includes :guest
    has_permission_on :users, :to => [:show, :edit ] do
    if_attribute :id => is { user.id }
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom index type routes use
    filter_access_to :all

Rather than
    filter_resource_access

got me too.

Answer (score 1):

I use AuthLogic, but as far as I know "current_user" is not going to be accessible through a route.

You would need to check, in the controller, if params[:id] == "current_user" (as a string) and then do some logic based on that... i.e:

```
if params[:id] == "current_user"
  @user_id = current_user.id
else
  @user_id = params[:id]
end
@user = User.find(@user_id)
```

A very simplistic example, but it should illustrate the type of logic you're going to need to get the current_user from a custom route.
You could also just map a named route for current_user to it's own controller action, but that's not very RESTful and would [most likely] duplicate functionality you already have.

Comment: Slipped my mind, and I wanted to ask:
Is there any reason in particular that would prevent you from just using user_path(current_user.id) to generate links? Or does the URL for a current_user *need* to be accessed?

Comment: actually trying to NOT use current_user in paths/URL's.  for a user to get to their home path it would be /profile and edit would be /profile/edit, etc.  Now the prob is declarative authorization needs to access the user id, I guess from the url route.  Not really sure, that's why I'm asking.